# Control a Windows apps using Java

Tags: java, windows

I would like to know if there is any way I can control a Windows application using Java code. I have already googled it, and found that it can be done using JNI or a library called NewJawin.

I want to control Windows Media Player using Java code, e.g. play, pause, and change songs, but could find no relevant example to get me started so far. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: Will controlling the mouse/keyboard work, as i can think of a way to do this by using the java.awt.Robot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As no one has answered this question, I thought I would.

```
public void firePlay() {
    //CTRL + P
    //import java.awt.Robot
    //import java.awt.KeyEvent
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(atest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This would play/pause the video. You can see other shortcuts [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Windows-Media-Player-keyboard-shortcuts)(http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Windows-Media-Player-keyboard-shortcuts)