# Finding keycode of multimedia key in java

Tags: java, awt, keyboard-events, keylistener

I want to capture key presses on Windows like Fn+Pause, Fn+VolumeUp in my Java Application but I am unable to detect their KeyCodes.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
        }
    });
```

Using this snippet it prints 0 for all the Multimedia Key Presses !

Kindly suggest a suitable method for finding the keyCode and thereby utilizing it in Java Application.

Comment: *"Kindly suggest a suitable method for finding the keyCode.."*  JNI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ***[JIntellitype](https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/)*** library.

This API is a Java JNI library that uses a C++ DLL to do all the communication with Windows.
That also means the platform on which you are running must be Windows.

If you are in Linux use ***[JXGrabKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/)***

In MacOSX use ***[OSSupport](https://bitbucket.org/agynamix/ossupport-connector)***

Answer (score 0):

Check the `KeyEvent` constants for *some* special keys. 
Other special keys might indeed not be "recognized".

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236303/keyevent-special-keys-like-mute) thread as well.